# Formatting Help in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I miss the formatting help in the app. If I don't remember I now have to go to the website to look.
Even nicer would be (additionally) some form of WYSIWYG editing / formatting help buttons.
Also a live preview of typed stuff would be nice if possible offline.